Liquibase 4.24.0 Unexpected Error Connection Closed when recreating Objects
We have an issue that just came up recently with our Liquibase Deployments. We run Liquibase 4.24.0 on Windows 10 Deploying to Postgresql.
After it gets to the step where we rebuild our Functions and Procedures, it errors out:
"Unexpected Error running Liquibase: This Connection has been Closed"
We added fine logging to the process and the log says
[2024-06-26 11:22:02] INFO [liquibase.command] Update command encountered an exception.
[2024-06-26 11:22:02] WARNING [liquibase.lockservice] Failed to release change log lock
[2024-06-26 11:22:02] WARNING [liquibase.command] Update command encountered exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.showSqlWarnings(JdbcExecutor.java:105)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:86)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:222)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:230)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:238)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:253)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:248)
    at liquibase.database.core.DatabaseUtils.initializeDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:41)
    at liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase.rollback(PostgresDatabase.java:404)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:415)
    at liquibase.command.core.AbstractUpdateCommandStep.doRun(AbstractUpdateCommandStep.java:125)
    at liquibase.command.core.AbstractUpdateCommandStep.lambda$run$0(AbstractUpdateCommandStep.java:63)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:184)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:183)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:162)
    at liquibase.command.core.AbstractUpdateCommandStep.run(AbstractUpdateCommandStep.java:62)
    at liquibase.command.core.UpdateCommandStep.run(UpdateCommandStep.java:106)
    at com.datical.liquibase.ext.command.ProUpdateCommandStep.run(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:214)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:55)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:24)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:383)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:358)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:356)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseLauncher.main(LiquibaseLauncher.java:133)

This error happens at the same procedure every time. If we remove the procedure, it runs and fails at a different procedure downstream. These procedures have not changed in between working and non-working deployments. Any ideas as to what is going on? We don't want to "upgrade" as we are trying to keep our test and production environments in sync.

I have exactly the same problem and behavior with liquibase 4.27.0. When the master.xml processes about 40 changelogs the connection is closed more or less halfway, but at a different changelog each time.
